# Bootstrap 3 form 2 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a bootstrap horizontal form with 2 columns. The issue i'm running into is not everything on the second column is going to have something and I need to make an "empty space" of the size of the first column.

I'm trying to have the end time label be inline with the start time label.

```
<form class="form-horizontal container" role="form" name="event" ng-controller="eventFormController">
    <div class="row hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="selectBusinesses" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Businesses</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <select id="selectBusinesses" class="form-control" ng-model="event.business" name="businesses"  ng-options=""></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="selectEventType" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2  control-label">Event Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <select id="selectEventType" class="form-control" ng-model="event.eventType" name="eventType" ng-options=""></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2control-label">Status</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    {{event.status}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTopic" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Topic</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTopic" ng-model="event.topic" name="topic" ng-maxlength="100" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputStartTime" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Start Time</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <timepicker ng-model="event.startTime" hour-step="hStep" minute-step="mStep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <span class="form-group"></span>
            <span class="form-group"></span>
            <span class="form-group"></span>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEndTime" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">End Time</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <timepicker ng-model="event.endTime" hour-step="hStep" minute-step="mStep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: offset]

As you can see the End time doesn't match up with the start time. I'm unsure what the best way to approach this. Should I split each form-group instead of having two columns?

Comment: put it in a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsFiddle.net) with the css please

Comment: Yes you should split each `form-group` if you want to align vertically input on left and right. 

Each `col` class has a predefinite size so it's easily to aligne 2 cols in 2 differents rows. But `row` does not have height, so it is not possible (by default) to aligne 2 row in 2 different cols.

Comment: tough to solve with the limited info, but I would think a wrapper would work here.  wrap the entire form with `position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;` then for the end time group set `position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;` maybe?

Comment: I got it to work with the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, it's not so diffucult to solve this issue, my solution would be putting each form-group in separate rows and if you want them to be inline, you can just keep them in the same row. That's something like table.

Now try this :

```
<form class="form-horizontal container" role="form" name="event" ng-controller="eventFormController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="selectBusinesses" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Businesses</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <select id="selectBusinesses" class="form-control" ng-model="event.business" name="businesses"  ng-options=""></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="selectEventType" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2  control-label">Event Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <select id="selectEventType" class="form-control" ng-model="event.eventType" name="eventType" ng-options=""></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2control-label">Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                {{event.status}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputTopic" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Topic</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTopic" ng-model="event.topic" name="topic" ng-maxlength="100" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputStartTime" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Start Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <timepicker ng-model="event.startTime" hour-step="hStep" minute-step="mStep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEndTime" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label">End Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <timepicker ng-model="event.endTime" hour-step="hStep" minute-step="mStep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this without the row for each row. works just the way I want. Cheers.